# Is a Komputerbay 4GB DDR3 compatible with a Kingston 4 GB DDR3-1333 DDR3?

Tags: memory, ddr3

They pretty much look the same to me, but I would like to confirm on this before purchasing.

I currently have a 4GB RAM Card:

```
DIMM1: Kingston 99U5471-012.A00LF   4 GB DDR3-1333 DDR3 SDRAM  (8-8-8-22 @ 609 MHz)  (7-7-7-20 @ 533 MHz)  (6-6-6-17 @ 457 MHz)
```

And I want to buy a new card from another brand, Komputerbay

```
Komputerbay 4GB DDR3 SODIMM (204 pin) 1333Mhz PC3 10600 8 GB (9-9-9-25)
```

Will they work okay together? I have two slots, so it's going to be 8 GB of RAM with both cards.

Comment: What you want to purchase is not compatible with your motherboard.  You should purchase the same brand if you can.

Comment: Same brand? No. Same *pinout*? yes. Ideally you want same or better speed, timing and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Komputerbay RAM is SODIMM which means it's only for laptops/notebooks. It's smaller, cheaper and works only in 204pin socket. My motherboard requires DIMM memory of 240pin. I was lucky to find the same memory I have on-board to avoid incompatibilities.